# How to refactor across multiple projects in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, add-in

I have a master solution with many projects inside, mostly class libraries for my other applications to use. Early in the project I needed to change a class name inside one of my libraries but VS would not let me refactor the name over all the projects, just the original library project. Is there a add-in that can help me do this or will i just have to use the rename command and change it from project to project?

Comment: The refactor command should work across all references in all currently loaded projects. It certainly does in 2010 and I'm almost certain it did in 2008. But if it doesn't work you can just use find-and-replace for "entire solution" (press CTRL+SHIFT+H),. Be sure to check "match case" and "match whole word", and review the results afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use resharper for doing this. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ 
It has a more features than the VS refactor.